# Can I prevent a mouse drag from unmaximizing a window?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, window, maximized

Ubuntu 20.04

I often drag the titlebar or scrollbar of a maximized window by mistake, causing it to unmaximize and get repositioned.

I have disabled "Edge Tiling" in Gnome Tweaks, and this is useful in preventing the opposite behaviour (auto-maximized windows). But how can I prevent windows being unmaximized by a mouse drag?